# handle_info() is not able to execute multiple calls concurrently

Tags: c++, asynchronous, erlang, gen-server

I have a program (C++ app) in which multiple threads are calling "handle_info()" written in an erlang module (genserver).

It is observed that, If thread-1 sends bunch of messages (say 1000) to this "handle_info()" and at the same time if Thread-2 also sends 1 or 2 messages at the same time to "handle_info()", it is observed that, handle_info() executes messages sent by Thread-2 only when it finishes the messages sent by Thread-1.

I have read that handle_info() is asynchronous, but in this case I find it to be working like synchronous method.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Note :

1. Thread-1 and Thread-2 are spawned by the same erlang module, and the thread function is from a C++ applications.
2. Thread function calls handle_info() using "enif_send()" function (erl_nif.h).

Comment: Please show us your code, so we can see if there are any errors that might cause this.

Comment: How are they ***calling*** `handle_info()`?

Comment: handle_info is being called using enif_send() function. It gets called successfully. But almost every time I have observed that the Thread-1 messages are processed first by handle_info() and then at a later point it processes Thread-2 messages.

Answer (score 1):

> it is observed that, handle_info() executes messages sent by Thread-2
>   only when it finishes the messages sent by Thread-1.

It sounds to me like Thread-1 sends all its messages before Thread-2 sends any messages.  The `gen_server` OTP behavior does not use selective receives to process messages, i.e. the implementation does not search through the server's mailbox trying to match a receive pattern against a message.  Instead, `gen_server` processes each message in the server's mailbox sequentially, i.e. in the order that the messages arrive in the mailbox.

The purpose of that design is to prevent memory leaks.  Such leaks occur when unhandled messages accumulate in the mailbox.  `gen_server:call/cast` send a message that lands in the server's mailbox (or an exit signal is converted to a message and placed in the server's mailbox, or a socket causes a message to be placed in the server's mailbox, or someone sends a message directly to the server with `!`), and the server processes the messages in the mailbox in the order they arrive.  For each message, the server calls the appropriate callback function:

```
Mod:handle_call()
Mod:handle_cast()
Mod:handle_info()
```

depending on the format of the message and removes the message from the mailbox.